# Creating a two column ordered list. Can I put a DIV between the OL and LI tags?

Tags: html, css

Using the 960.gs framework, I'm trying to create a two columned ordered list where each list item contains a heading and paragraph and the numbering goes across, not down e.g. the top row contains 1,2 not 1,3. The only way I can get it to work is to put a DIV between the OL and LI elements. This doesn't feel right, I'm sure its wrong although I'm not sure why. What is the correct way to achieve this? I've got the following markup;

```
<div class="container_16">
<ol>
    <div class="grid_8">
        <li><h2>Heading</h2>
            <p>Paragraph</p>
        </li>
    </div>
    <div class="grid_8">
        <li><h2>Heading</h2>
            <p>Paragraph</p>
        </li>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="grid_8">
        <li><h2>Heading</h2>
            <p>Paragraph</p>
        </li>    
    </div>
    <div class="grid_8">
        <li><h2>Heading</h2>
            <p>Paragraph</p>
        </li>    
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is invalid to place `div` elements inside the `ol` tag.

Only `li` elements are allowed in there.. ([check the W3C documentation on lists](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#h-10.2))

The theory is to use

```
ol{width:200px;}
li{float:left;width:50%;}
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/ZKdpf/1/

---

For the `960.gs` system you should use

```
<ol class="container_16">
    <li class="grid_8">first</li>
    <li class="grid_8">second</li>
    <li class="grid_8">third</li>
    <li class="grid_8">fourth</li>
    <li class="grid_8">fifth</li>
    <li class="grid_8">sixth</li>
</ol>
```

and add in your css

```
ol.container_16 li.grid_8{
   display:list-item;
}
```

to show the numbers again..

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/ZKdpf/2/

---

**Update**

Indeed as you mention in your comment you need to clear every two elements, since the height of the `li` elements is not the same..

For modern browsers you should add

```
.benefits li:nth-child(odd) {
    clear: left;
}
```

or your can turn that in a class and add it to the odd numbered `li` elements.

Comment: That looks much better. The 960.gs example works but I'm having problems clearing the li's. How would I best clear each row? I tried adding "clear:both" to every second one but that didnt work.

Comment: @Michell, there should be no need to clear them... since the container `ol` has a class of `container_16` and all the `li` elements have a class of `grid_8` they should wrap on their own, because only two can fit in the container.. do you have a live example of the problem because it might be other css rules that interfere..

Comment: Here is the problem - http://goo.gl/q7rL7 - As you can see, after the 4th li element, it seems it need a clear. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You right to 'feel wrong'.  Lists contain list-items and nothing else.  The easiest way, I think to achieve a horizontal numbering, is to float your LIs.

Answer (score 0):

The above source code is wront. You can't place anything else between

```
<ol></ol>
```

except

```
 <li></li>
```

elements. You propably have to find another way to style out your lists.